# Dart: Find first digit in String and cut the String

Tags: date, dart, formatting

I have a string like this:

"tuesday 04.08.2020" or
"wednesday 05.08.2020"

and i will cut the day (tuesday or wednesday) so that my string is in the following format:

"04.08.2020" or
"05.08.2020"

How can i found the first digit in a string and become this format. I don't have found a solution in dart yet. In other languages (e.g. javascript or python) it gives a search function, but in the dart language i don't find a function like this. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to find the first digit.
This will work

```
String a = "tuesday 04.08.2020";
String date = a.split(" ").last;
print(date);//04.08.2020
```